# Filter Tags for current users

Tags: custom-taxonomy, tags

I have a custom post type call question which have custom taxonomies which is called question-tags. These question tag further used for creating dynamic quiz. I want to restrict users to use question-tags created by them only.
They cann't access tags created by others. How it is possible?

Just let me know how to make tags private for each user so they cann't use tags create by each other in front end forms

Comment: i didn't tried much thing, since i am new php. But i tired make id do by using code    if ( is_user_logged_in() ):

   ` global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    $author_query = array(
   'posts_per_page' => '-1',
   'author' => $current_user->ID,
   'post_type'=>'question'
);` This code is helpful for displaying current user's custom post, but didn't helped me in tags

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way of doing this.
Whenever a new term is created, you execute the following code.

This code saves the current user_id as the term author, which should allow you to filter by user_id when fetching terms.

```
add_action( 'created_term', 'filter_user_specific_term', 10, 3 );

function filter_user($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy){
    if( $taxonomy == "my_custom_taxonomy"){
        if (isset($term_id)) {
            add_term_meta ($term_id, "author", get_current_user_id());
        }
    }
}
```

To get the term list, according to current user:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_taxonomy',
    'meta_key' => 'author',
    'meta_value' => get_current_user_id() ) );
```

I didn't test this code but should be a good start point for doing what you want.

Comment: i put code for filter user_id in my function.php and other code where i want to get terms but it doesn't work

Comment: What do you get?